# how to upgrade typescript to a new major version

Tags: typescript, npm

The typescript runtime in my git repo still shows 4.9.5 even after I upgraded all packages and deleted node_modules and package-lock.json and re-installed with `npm install`.

How can I get the `tsc` version to be more recent than 5.0 ?

```
$ npx tsc --version
Version 4.9.5

$ ./node_modules/.bin/tsc --version
Version 4.9.5
```

I have a NPM monorepo where all packages list "typescript" as a dev dependency. A while back I used "npm uninstall typescript" on each package, then re-added via "npm install typescript -D" so the package dependencies listed the new major version (was v4, now v5).

When I build one of my packages (create-react-app) it shows me ESLint believes I'm using typescript version 4.9.5.

```
WARNING: You are currently running a version of TypeScript which is not officially supported by @typescript-eslint/typescript-estree.

You may find that it works just fine, or you may not.

SUPPORTED TYPESCRIPT VERSIONS: >=3.3.1 <4.9.0

YOUR TYPESCRIPT VERSION: 4.9.5

Please only submit bug reports when using the officially supported version.
```

None of my package.json files or package-lock.json file display v4. All show v5.

```
$ npm list --depth=0 | grep -i typescript
│ └── typescript@5.0.4
│ └── typescript@5.0.4
│ ├── typescript@5.0.4
│ └── typescript@5.0.4
│ ├── typescript@5.0.4
│ ├── @babel/preset-typescript@7.22.5
│ ├── typescript@5.0.4
│ ├── typescript@5.0.4
│ ├── typescript@5.0.4
│ ├── @babel/preset-typescript@7.22.5 deduped
│ ├── @rollup/plugin-typescript@11.1.0
│ └── typescript@5.0.4
│ ├── typescript@5.1.3
│ ├── typescript@5.0.4
│ └── typescript@5.0.4
│ └── typescript@5.0.4
│ └── typescript@5.0.4
│ └── typescript@5.0.4
│ └── typescript@5.0.4
│ ├── typescript@5.0.4
│ ├── typescript@5.0.4
│ ├── typescript@5.0.4
│ ├── typescript@5.1.6
│ ├── typescript@5.0.4
│ ├── typescript@5.0.4
│ ├── @babel/preset-typescript@7.22.5 deduped
│ ├── typescript@5.0.4
│ ├── typescript@5.0.4
│ └── typescript@5.0.4
│ ├── typescript@5.1.6
│ └── typescript@5.0.4
│ └── typescript@5.0.4
│ ├── typescript@5.0.4
│ └── typescript@5.0.4
│ └── typescript@5.1.5
│ └── typescript@5.0.4
```

I am currently using node 16.19 and npm 8.11 via nvm.

```
$ node --version
v16.19.1
$ npm --version
8.19.3
```

---

EDIT: This post is about Typescript, not React or Create-React-App, in a NPM workspaces (mono) repo. Sorry for any confusion.

Comment: What does the `package.json` file says about typescript?

Comment: This is a ltitle weird. Have you tried deleting `node_modules` and `npm install` again? It's as if the symlink didn't get updated. Also Alejandro is right, you should also have a top level "typescript" entry in your top level package.json and set it to 5.

Comment: @Alejandro my repo's top-level package.json has no reference to typescript. For the other package.json files, "I have a NPM monorepo where all packages list "typescript" as a dev dependency."

Comment: @adsy from my post, "my git repo still shows 4.9.5 even after I upgraded all packages and deleted node_modules and package-lock.json and re-installed with npm install".

Comment: I think i found your issue: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/13080

Comment: @adsy That is part of the issue. Thanks for trying. I was able to get `npx tsc --version` to show the right version with `npm install --save-dev typescript` in my top-level package.json. It still works after uninstalling `typescript` from my top-level package.json. CRA's ESLint now complains that I'm using an "unsupported version 5.2.2". I guess that's what I get for using CRA.

Comment: Yeh so taking a step back, what is happening is that `create-react-app` and/or one or more of its deps demands a TS version that is 4.x.x and that is getting prioritised. The reason seems to be inherent incompatibility in `create-react-app`. They haven't upgraded its deps to versions which support this version of TS. `create-react-app` is actually a little dead sadly, hence why it hasn't happened. You might be able to get eslint to work by using `overrides` to force it to a newer version, as well as all the eslint plugins and parser packages. Hacky though...i'd be looking to move off it.

Comment: Worth looking at https://github.com/reactjs/react.dev/pull/5487 for some of the discourse about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are

1. using a NPM workspaces monorepo,
2. and the nested packages have a (dev) dependency on Typescript,
3. and you've upgraded the typescript version,
4. but `npx tsc --version` still shows the old version

For example:

```
$ cd <repo_clone_directory>

$ ls -1 packages/
micro-service-1
micro-service-2
ui-1
ui-2

$ npx tsc --init
Version 4.9.5
```

Then you probably need to ADD a (dev) dependency on Typescript in your top-level `package.json` file.

```
$ cd <repo_clone_directory>

$ npm install typescript

$ npx tsc --version
Version 5.2.2
```

And if your CreateReactApp package is complaining that your typescript version is not supported when ESLint runs, then you should

1. temporarily disable ESLint.
2. eventually migrate to [vitejs](https://vitejs.dev/) as CRA has been abandoned.

From `packages/ui-1/package.json`

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "DISABLE_ESLINT_PLUGIN=true react-scripts start",
    "build": "DISABLE_ESLINT_PLUGIN=true react-scripts build",
```

EDIT: Adding "typescript" to the top-level package.json also helps with minor version upgrades.